# I need to pass string value from index 1. i have code in swift 1.2 but i can't get desired output in swift 3

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift3, swift2

```
cString = cString.substring(from: advance(cString.startIndex, 1))
```

//I'm new to swift3 please suggest me replace to this line in swift 3. Xcode is not able convert this line and giving error as Use of unresolved identifier advance..

Comment: can you explain with an example what you actually need to do?

Comment: viewToConfig.backgroundColor = UIColor.hexStringToUIColor("#007AFF")         if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {cString = cString.substring(from: advance(cString.startIndex, 1))} .       
           if(cString.characters.count != 6){
            return UIColor.gray
        }        /// to pass rgb value after # in second if condition Suryakant

Comment: see my answer below

Answer (score 1):

**Swift 3.0**

You need to use the String method `index(_:offsetBy:`) to advance the index:

```
let index = cString.index(cString.startIndex, offsetBy: 1)       
cString = cString.substring(from: index)
```

Comment: Thanks Jadeep it's working. i have tried it in many ways..now it was fixed thanks

Comment: @yogi if you found answer useful you can accept it, so another users can directly use it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm also using this in some of my projects, you can use this as well

```
func colorWithHexString (_ hex:String, alpha: Float) -> UIColor {

           var cString:String = hex.trim()

            if (cString.hasPrefix("#")) {
                cString = (cString as NSString).substring(from: 1)
            }

            if (cString.characters.count != 6) {
                return UIColor.gray
            }

            let rString = (cString as NSString).substring(to: 2)
            let gString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 2) as NSString).substring(to: 2)
            let bString = ((cString as NSString).substring(from: 4) as NSString).substring(to: 2)

            var r:CUnsignedInt = 0, g:CUnsignedInt = 0, b:CUnsignedInt = 0;
            Scanner(string: rString).scanHexInt32(&r)
            Scanner(string: gString).scanHexInt32(&g)
            Scanner(string: bString).scanHexInt32(&b)

            return UIColor(red: CGFloat(r) / 255.0, green: CGFloat(g) / 255.0, blue: CGFloat(b) / 255.0, alpha: CGFloat(alpha))
    }
```